# Cannot call 'plot' error for pine-script Elliot Wave indicator

Tags: trading, indicator, pine-script-v4, technical-indicator

I can't seem to find the solution to fix the 2 following errors

Error at 26:0 Cannot call 'plot' with 'title'=string. The argument should be of type: const string;
Error at 36:0 Cannot call 'plot' with 'title'=series[string]. The argument should be of type: const string

This is my current code, if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be a major help

````
//@version=4
study("Elliot Wave", overlay=true)

// Define the swing high and low points
var swingHigh = high >= high[1] and high >= high[-1] and high > high[-2]
var swingLow = low <= low[1] and low <= low[-1] and low < low[-2]

// Initialize variables
var trend = 0.0
var direction = 0.0
var lastHigh = 0.0
var lastLow = 0.0
var waveCount = 0
var lastWaveHigh = 0.0
var lastWaveLow = 0.0

// Loop through the price data and identify the waves
for i = 2 to bar_index
    if swingHigh[i]
        if trend == -1
            // We have a wave completion, mark the end point
            lastWaveHigh := lastHigh
            plot(lastWaveHigh, "Wave " + tostring(waveCount), color=color.purple, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_stepline)
            waveCount += 1
        // New wave started, mark the start point
        lastHigh := high[i]
        trend := 1
        direction := -1
    if swingLow[i]
        if trend == 1
            // We have a wave completion, mark the end point
            lastWaveLow := lastLow
            plot(lastWaveLow, "Wave " + tostring(waveCount), color=color.purple, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_stepline)
            waveCount += 1
        // New wave started, mark the start point
        lastLow := low[i]
        trend := -1
        direction := 1

// Plot the wave direction for bullish trend
var lastWaveHighIndex = bar_index - barssince(swingHigh)
plot(lastWaveHigh + direction * (bar_index - lastWaveHighIndex), "Bullish Wave", color=color.green, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_stepline)

// Plot the wave direction for bearish trend
var lastWaveLowIndex = bar_index - barssince(swingLow)
plot(lastWaveLow + direction * (bar_index - lastWaveLowIndex), "Bearish Wave", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_stepline)```


 I have tried moving the plot calls inside the corresponding if statements. however it caused another error entirely.

Cannot use 'plot' in local scope.;
````

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript, you can't use plot in the local scope (in an if or a for loop).
Then, with plot, you can't use 'variable' that change for the title wich must be a constant string = a string that cannot change like "My String Example).
See : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_plot